# How can I revert pip uninstall?

Tags: python, linux, pip, sudo, su

I made a mistake by using `su -c 'pip3 install' --upgrade pip'` to upgrade pip because I got errors when trying to upgrade it as a normal user.

This removed the pre-installed pip and dumped it in `/tmp`, replacing it with a system wide installation of pip which is only accessible by root. If I try to uninstall the root controlled pip then I think that it would cause problems so I haven't tried to.

How do I get back the pre-installed pip using the executable that is still in `/tmp`?

#### Location of pip in /tmp:

```
/tmp/pip-ufkfr3th-uninstall
└── usr
    └── bin
        └── pip
```

Comment: What is your distribution?

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I'm using fedora

Comment: So check what is the version of python and edit if need `yum` command. And do not use binary from `/tmp`, reinstall is sample and safe

Comment: @Romeo Ninov I have both python 2 and python 3 installed.

Comment: So which one is default? And from which one is this pip package?

Comment: I think python 2 is default but not 100% sure. This pip package should be the python 3 version according to the command I ran.

Answer (score 1):

The command you should use is

```
sudo apt-get --reinstall install python-pip
```

or

```
sudo yum reinstall python27-python-pip
```

dependent of packaging system you use (DEB or RPM)

Comment: wouldn't this remove all the packages I have installed using pip? I prefer not to start from scratch.

Comment: No, it will reinstall only pip package.